# How to make my test loop through different paths in array in Postman

Tags: postman

Below is what I have currently written in my test.

I don't just want the GET to continue to get 0 because ID's in response are in chronological order.

So what's the easiest way to make my path a random number?

```
value = bodyData.data[0].id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `random(from, to)` function of Lodash.

```
const dataArr = bodyData.data;
const value = dataArr[_.random(0, dataArr.length - 1)].id
```

Comment: I tried this and still getting an error.                                                                                        const data = bodyData.data 
const value = data[_.random(0, data.length - 1)].id

console.log(value)

pm.environment.set("ContactId", value);

Comment: Oh, I understand, because `data` is reserved var in postman, you have to choose another name. I've updated my answer.